# how to check if file exists in Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

When using the database you can do `snapshot.exists()` to check if certain data exists. According to the docs there isn't a similar method with storage.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference

What is the proper way of checking if a certain file exists in Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firebase added an .exists() method. Another person responded and mentioned this, but the sample code they provided is incorrect. I found this thread while searching for a solution myself, and I was confused at first because I tried their code but it always was returning "File exists" even in cases when a file clearly did not exist.

exists() returns an array that contains a boolean. The correct way to use it is to check the value of the boolean, like this:

```
const storageFile = bucket.file('path/to/file.txt');
storageFile
  .exists()
  .then((exists) => {
        if (exists[0]) {
          console.log("File exists");
        } else {
          console.log("File does not exist");
        }
     })
```

I'm sharing this so the next person who finds this thread can see it and save themselves some time.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any Google documentation for this method? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @GrantSingleton I have not been able to find any official documentation on it myself either.

Comment: @GrantSingleton Correction: there is one reference. Another poster shared it in a comment further down on this same topic, if you scroll down. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/5.1.1/File.html#exists-examples

Comment: make sure to check `exists[0]` and not `exists`. that was my ire

Comment: Where does bucket come from?

Comment: @BrandonPillay For me it comes from: `const fbAdmin = require('firebase-admin'); const bucketName = projectId + '.appspot.com'; const bucket = fbAdmin.storage().bucket(bucketName);`

Comment: are there any costs associated with this method?

Comment: @dovigz I'm not sure on costs. Here is the link to cloud storage pricing: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing

To me it feels like exists() could be a class B operation (which cost $.004 per 10k in 2022 pricing), but it is not explicitly listed. Firebase also includes 50k free operations per month. I don't use exists at a high enough volume to see any impact on my current costs. 

You could try running a quantity of exists operations to see if they show up in your billing, or contact Firebase support to ask if they can clarify.

Comment: since 5.1.1 was long ago, and google is not a good resource for finding these API docs, just confirming this IS an official documented function, but afaict ONLY in the server/admin API.  Presumably the /latest docs path will remain valid even as versions change: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#exists

Answer (score 36):

You can use [getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) which returns a [Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Thenable), which can in turn be used to catch a "not found" error, or process the file if it exists. For example:

```
storageRef.child("file.png").getDownloadURL().then(onResolve, onReject);

function onResolve(foundURL) {
    //stuff
}

function onReject(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Warning: might be costly if you have several thousands of documents as downloading url will be priced by Firebase.

Comment: @CorentinHoudayer He is giving reference with file_name. So there is only one file. Why will it be costly?

Comment: @Unknown2433 If you download only this document once in your app for a single user, the answer is no. If you do it multiple times (each app launch) with multiple files, yes it will become pretty expensive. Take a look at firebase pricing and you can estimate your budget based on this.

Comment: @CorentinHoudayer I am not downloading the file. I am requesting for the download url of the file and calling `getDownloadUrl` is free. Isn't it?

Comment: @Unknown2433 It isn't free as you will consume bandwidth which has a cost. I had an app where I was showing wallpapers, using this request 50 times / per session on average was really expensive for me. Even more if you download the file using URL of course.

In order to know the consumed bandwidth, you might do your own test on Android with a specific app for instance.

Comment: @CorentinHoudayer I know about bandwidth cost which is the worst thing about firebase storage. But I didn't knew that calling `getDownloadUrl` uses bandwidth. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the FB storage API is setup in a way that the user only request a file that exists.

Thus a non-existing file will have to be handled as an error:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors

Answer (score 6):

I've found a nice solution while keeping within the Node.js Firebase Gogole Cloud Storage SDK using the [File.exists](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/5.1.1/File.html#exists), taught it would be ideal to share for those searching.

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('my-bucket');

const storageFile = bucket.file('path/to/file.txt');
storageFile
  .exists()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("File exists");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("File doesn't exist");
  });
```

*[Google Cloud Storage: Node.js SDK version 5.1.1 (2020-06-19)](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/5.1.1/index.html) at the time of writing*

Comment: The example code is wrong. Check the example on the docs: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/5.1.1/File.html#exists-examples

Comment: Bucket doesn't have property file

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me

```
  Future<bool> fileExists(String file) async {
    var parts = file.split('/');
    var path = parts.sublist(0, parts.length - 1).join('/');
    var listResult = await _storage.ref().child(path).list();
    return listResult.items.any((element) => element.fullPath == file);
  }
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for an image and using the cached_network_image package you can use the built in error listener. E.g.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: logoURL,
  errorListener: (context) {
    setState(() {
      logoExists = false;
    });
    print('no image');
  },
),
```