# How to check the particular file already exist when uploading on Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I upload a file to the Firebase storage I need to check the relevant file name already exist or not. In Firebase database we can do it using `snapshot.exists()`. But in Firebase storage I can't find anything regarding that.

I went through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage), but it does not provide better solution for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if file exists in Firebase Storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage)

Comment: @cartant Read my question first. I have linked that question.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with a question's answers, you can place a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it: *"If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers."* However, I don't think it should be re-asked.

Comment: The answer to the linked question is the stated method: you can check for existence by making a query for the object and seeing if you get a non-404 back.