# How to check existence of a file in Firebase Storage without logging an error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Basically, I want to check if a file exists on a specific location on FB Storage If so then, do some Stuff else some other stuff needs to be executed.

so far I have tried this

```
const profile_pic = firebase.storageRef
        .child(`profile_pics/${uid}/}`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          setProfileImage(url);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // show Default userPic    
          console.log("err >> ", err);
        });
```

This code Resembles the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage?rq=1#:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20database%20you,check%20if%20certain%20data%20exists.)

This Code works Fine BUT BUT BUT It still logs Error on the console.
[image]

All I'm Looking for is the best way to get it done without logging Error On console. Any help is Appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You tagged with `node.js` and with `reactjs`, but the code seems to be using the regular [Firebase JavaScript SDK for accessing Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage). I updated the tags to reflect this. If the Node.js or React.js tag *is* relevant to the problem, feel free to add it back **and clarify why it's relevant in the question.

Comment: No I think both were Irrelevant Tags... I just Added them coz I was using that tech stack for better understanding, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const profile_pic = firebase.storageRef
        .child(`profile_pics/${uid}/}`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener(){

        {
          setProfileImage(url);
        })
          .catch((err) => {   
           console.log("err >> ", err);
        }

        });
```

Try this

Comment: as expeced I got this err --> ```MapboxGl-MAP.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: _Firebase_Fbase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.storageRef.child(...).getDownloadURL(...).addOnSuccessListener is not a function
    at get_coords (MapboxGl-MAP.js:65)
    at MapboxGl-MAP.js:296
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487)```

Comment: you are using java/javascript to code right ?

Comment: yup.. I'm using JavaScript