# How to check if a file exists in my firebase storage in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I tried to do it like how they do it in this post's answer [how to check if file exists in Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage)

But I keep getting a error when I try to use that @google-cloud/storage package.
Is there another way of checking if a file exists without catching and throwing an error?

This is how I'm currently uploading the file, which is an image, to my firebase

```
 firebase.storage().ref('users/'+user.uid + '/profile.jpg').put(file.target.files[0]).then( () => {
      console.log("Successfully uploaded image")
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error uploading image: " + error);
    });
```

This is the line of code that causes it to break

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

And I get this error in the console. util.js:602 Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong with the method described in the other answer?

Comment: It requires me to use the ```@google-cloud/storage``` package. And when I try to import it into my program, it causes it to break. I'll edit the post to add the line of code that causes the error