# firebase storage custom html page for errors like permission denied?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way to show a custom html page or redirect a user when storage throws errors like if file is not available, not sufficient permissions or in case of any other issues when the file can't be accessed/displayed?

So instead of the below

[image]

We need to show a custom page with our brand designs.

What are the options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.  You are using an API endpoint (download URL) meant for programmatic consumption or inline page insertion, not for loading into a browser to present a full web page.

Comment: Got you. Is there a way to know if that API will throw an error or return an object without triggering the actual download?

Comment: I dunno, try a HEAD request?

Comment: thanks, seems to be an option. I've also found this discussion - I'll leave it here in case anyone else might find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751202/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-firebase-storage